# calling two ajax requests and appending both in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

here’s my project, I’m using to ajax requests

one to load all the streams

and another one to get the online stream information

as none of the APIs has information about both online and offline streams together

so I have successfully loaded all streams with their names and logos

I want to do changes to the stream div (add the status, change background color to green) if the stream is online

here’s what I’ve tried

streamers array

```
var streamer = ["Thulz","ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas","Rakin"];
```

for loop fetching every streamer, first ajax for fetching every streamer and putting them in a div each, second one is where I’m struggling

```
for(i=0;i<streamer.length;i++){
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/"+streamer[i],
    success: function(response) {

    $("#result").append("<div class='row streams'><div class='col-12 imag'><img src='"+response.logo+"' alt='"+response.name+"' height='75' width='75'><div class='texts'>"+response.name+"<p id='"+response.name+"'></p></div></div></div>");          
}});//first AJAX

    $.ajax({//second ajax
    url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/"+streamer[i],
    success: function(online) {
        if(online.stream !== null){
            console.log(online.stream.channel.status);
        }
    }//response success
            });

}//streamer for loop
```

what I’ve tried:

giving a unique #id to every streamer and then append the status and perform the css changes to the streamers the second request gets

```
$("#"+streamer[i]).append(online.stream.channel.status);
```

or

```
var sname= online.stream.channel.name;
$("#"+sname).append(online.stream.channel.status);
```

none worked, help!

Comment: Wait for second request to complete before appending the data from the first. Then build whatever html you need using both responses

Comment: I've tried your code and it works, of course you added jQuery link, right?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Krimlen/pen/EvPOEg here's the codepen, how is it not working for me?

Comment: Not working, ok ... First of all, I see at line 17 I see you used `$("#"+streamer[i]).append(online.stream.channel.status);` try to change it to `$("#"+streamer).append(online.stream.channel.status);`

Comment: same result, should I just store each object in a global variable then build the html below both before the end of the loop?

Comment: ok now instead of streamer[i] i used online.stream.channel.name which is the same name, it works but sometimes i refresh and it'd have 3 online and only show two or one

Comment: Look at the console.log: https://codepen.io/tinchoeluru/pen/qXZRxR

Comment: the same is happening with me, I'm able to console log them but can't append them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered my question here https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/twitch-api-project-issue/139229/2

here's the answer

> The problem you are having is with the first A in AJAX. While you are
>   making asynchronous calls to the API and waiting for the responses,
>   your loop just continues with nothing set to hold the data when it
>   arrives. What you need to do is store the results of your AJAX calls
>   in variables, and when both variables have successfully acquired their
>   data, do something with that data:
>
> ```
> var a = $.ajax({ . . . }); //first AJAX
> var b = $.ajax({ . . . }); //second AJAX
>
> $.when(a, b).done(function(channelData, streamData) { . . . });
> ```
>
> The $.when().done() will keep track of the a and b variables for each
>   call in the loop and only proceed when both have arrived. Just put
>   your append() code in there and see if that does the trick. Also,
>   channelData and streamData just refer to a and b respectively. You
>   don’t have to use those variable names, that’s just what I used for my
>   Twitch app for clarity

my final codepen https://codepen.io/Krimlen/pen/rzejdV

the correct code

```
var streamer = ["Thulz","ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas","Rakin"];
for(i=0;i<streamer.length;i++){
var firstAjax = $.ajax({
url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/"+streamer[i]});//first AJAX
var secondAjax = $.ajax({//second ajax
url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/"+streamer[i]
});
$.when(firstAjax, secondAjax).done(function(channel, live) {

$("#result").append(*acess both ajax results here by the names channel and live and append them*);
```